How to set "Keyboard navigation" option via command line?
How can I turn on & off keyboard navigation toggle programmatically via command line?


Here are the commands:
Enable Keyboard Navigation
defaults write -g AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 2

Disable Keyboard Navigation
defaults write -g AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 0


It may work by accident, but AppleKeyboardUIMode is an int, not bool.

@PavelVlasov Confirmed. I spun up a test VM. I've updated my answer.

You can play with that UI switch and see how it changes settings:
defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleKeyboardUIMode

You'll see integer 0 when disabled and 2 when enabled. Thus...
Enable keyboard navigation:
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 2

Disable keyboard navigation:
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 0

Effect is immediate but you may need to restart an application.
Checked with macos 14.6, 14.7.
